# How to center chapter title in a specific area?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chapters, titlesec, center

[image]

I have this gorgeous custom made photo header which is perfect, however I want to center every chapter title in this sky blue area. I am currently using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11.5pt,twoside, openleft]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{-2pt}{\Huge \bfseries \mbox}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{186pt}{-120pt}{27pt}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
 \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Figures/TemplatePCourse/BackL.png}    
  \else
   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Figures/TemplatePCourse/BackR.png}    
  \fi
}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Velden}
\end{document}
```

I am using the `mbox`  to prevent linebreaks in my header. Is anybody able to help me with this problem?

Comment: Personally, I avoid titlesec and instead modify `\@makechapterhead` directly.  You can't really know what titlesec is doing without looking at the code, and titlesec is far more complicated than `\@makechapterhead`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{-2pt}{\hskipxcm\centering\Huge \bfseries \mbox} 
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-120pt}{27pt}
```

where xcm is the required distance (required by the specific image, unknown to me).

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain your code. For instance, `\hskipxcm` doesn't seem to be a valid command, and I guess you mean `hskip x cm`.

Comment: I edited my answer, but also I yet explained it  two comments ago.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you defined the header using maybe `fancyhdr` package by including some photo, and that you are including the chapter title and number In the header and not in the text, then this is my solution using `tikzpagenodes` package as well. All you need to do is adjust the 2nd parameter of `\titlespacing` command from the `titlesec` package. Note that I used the image named `download` as an example here. You are to replace the name with the one you are using.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11.5pt,twoside, openleft]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\color{white} \chaptername\ \thechapter}{-2pt}{\Huge \bfseries \mbox}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0.25\textwidth}{-100pt}{27pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter[Velden]{\color{white} Velden}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\lhead{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw  let \p1=($(current page.north)-(current page header area.south)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
node [inner sep=0,outer sep=0,below] 
      at (current page.north){\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\n1]{download}}; % Image name here
\end{tikzpicture}}
\chapter{Lucht}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Setting `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0.5\textwidth}{-100pt}{27pt}` gives

[image]

Finally, setting `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0.75\textwidth}{-100pt}{27pt}` gives

[image]

As suggested by @C. Peters, setting `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{-2pt}{\centering \Huge \bfseries \mbox}` yields-

[image]

Comment: The header is a photo which I made in Adobe Photoshop, so this wouldn't work

Comment: I used a photo in the header. So? As I mentioned earlier, You didn't explicitly mention in the code how you designed the header, whether you used `fancyhdr` or other ways.

Comment: Did you replace the image name I used here (`download`) with the one you are using? This is in the line `node [inner sep=0,outer sep=0,below] 
      at (current page.north){\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\n1]{download}};`

Comment: I just want to have a way to center the chapter title, while 'ignoring' the left purple side of the page.

Comment: The chapter title has nothing do with the image you are using here. As I said before, all you need to do is adjust the parameters in `\titlespacing` command.

Comment: Does \centering before \Huge solve your problem? Besides: the \chaptername is not visible in your title. Do you need it?

Comment: \centering does not work. And don't need \chaptername

Comment: @superHenry If you do not need `\chaptername` why did you include it in your code? and `centering` according to @C. Peters worked fine for me. As I already said, unless you don't include the code for the header, there's no way one can help you out with this.

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela Sorry, my mistake about the `chaptername`. However, if I put `centering` before my \Huge the chapter title centers in the middle of the page and not in the blue are. Furthermore, the point is that the header has no code, it is a (photo) background (Which I edited now in my question)

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela There are also bigger chapter titles, so changing the paramaters of `titlespacing` will work for this case, but it won't for bigger or smaller titles

Comment: We do not have your figure. From which point exactly do you want to measure the width of the blue part? The left lower point? According to me you should set the first argument of titlespacint to 0pt (because that shifts the title now to the right), then ad \hskipx\centering to the titleformat, where 'x' is the distant from the left you need to reach the point from where on you want to center.

Comment: @C.Peters so `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-120pt}{\hskip{xcm} \centering}` this would work?

Comment: No, in my previous comment I wrote first of titlespacing and then of titleformat: \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{-2pt}{\hskipxcm\centering\Huge \bfseries \mbox}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt
}{-120pt}{27pt}

Comment: @C.Peters It works! thank you so much for your time and patience!

Comment: @superHenry I put my solution in an answer and would be please if you accept it.